# CMake configure_file not being included in static library

Tags: c++, build, cmake

Directory structure is as follows:

```
project
   | ...
   | CMakeLists.txt
   | - build/
         | - bench/
               | libbench_main.a  // static library containing symbols
               | foo.h
   | - bench/
         | - bench_main.cc
         | - CMakeLists.txt
         | - foo.h.in
```

I want to `include foo.h` in `libbench_main.a`

```
// project/bench/bench_main.cc
#include "foo.h"
...

// project/bench/foo.h.in
#cmakedefine01 BAR
```

So the expected outcome as far as I understand it is that if I then do `nm` on libbench_main.a after building it I should see the `BAR` symbol.

The CMake also seems pretty straightforward to me, as far as CMake goes:

```
// project/bench/CMakeLists.txt
...
set(BAR FALSE)
configure_file(foo.h.in foo.h @ONLY)
add_library(bench_main STATIC bench_main.cc foo.h)
target_include_directories(bench_main PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
...
```

Right? So I configure the file, and after I run `cmake -GNinja ..` in `project/build` I get this:

```
// project/build/bench/foo.h
#define BAR 0
```

Everything is as expected. However, when I run `ninja bench/libbench_main.a` in `project/build` and actually build this, there's no errors, but `nm`-ing `project/build/bench/libbench_main.a` reveals that the symbol is not there. I have *no* idea how such a simple set of commands could fail to include it - it's very clearly in the CMake that it's meant to be added. This is with a clean `build` directory, I should add, so that will not be the issue.

This is on Ubuntu if that makes any difference, with CMake version 3.12.

Comment: `#define BAR 0` is a C preprocessor directive and as such does not define any symbol. You need to explicitly use this definition. For example: `const extern bool bar(BAR);` in your `*.cc` file

Comment: @Ptaq666 - Maybe that would be better given as an answer? And as an aside, would changing `project/bench/foo.h.in` to use a variable like `bool bar = @BAR@;` work, assuming I changed the CMake? Would that be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define BAR 0` is a C preprocessor directive and as such does not define any symbol. You need to explicitly use this definition. For example: `const extern bool bar(BAR);` in your `bench_main.cc`. It can also be defined directly in `foo.h.in` as `bool bar = @BAR@;` if you change your line in `CMakeLists.txt` to `set(BAR false)` (lowercase false). Just remember about [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) when playing with global variables.

Also there is no need to include your header in `add_library(bench_main STATIC bench_main.cc)`